# Configuring wildfly swarm Undertow fraction on yaml

Tags: java, spring, java-11, wildfly-swarm, thorntail

Failing to configure thorntail project-defaults.yaml based on existing (jboss)standalone.xml

**pom.xml** (using Thorntail 2.4.0.Final)

Am trying to upgrade thorntail application from java 8 to 11 - the application currently is using jboss 10. I have decided to move away from standalone.xml to projects-default.yaml as this will upgrade jboss/wildfly to the latest version based on thorntail 2.4.0.

Assist converting from

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:8.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="sdom">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/prop" handler="properties"/>
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-info"/>
                <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-info" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-info"  directory-listing="false"/>
            <file name="properties" path="${jboss.home.dir}/" directory-listing="true"/>
        </handlers>
    </subsystem>
```

To the yaml project-default - here is what i have done.

```
swarm:
  undertow:
    handler-configuration:
      files:
        default:
          path: "${jboss.home.dir}/"
          directory-listing: true
    servers:
      default:
        hosts:
          default:
            alias: localhost
            locations:
              default:
                handler: properties
            http-invoker-setting:
              security-realm: ApplicationRealm
        https-listeners:
          default:
            enable-http2: true
            security-realm: ApplicationRealm
            socket-binding: https
        http-listeners:
          default:
            enable-http2: true
            redirect-socket: https
            socket-binding: http
    servlet-containers:
      default:
        default-buffer-cache: default
    default-virtual-host: default-host
    default-servlet-container: default
    default-server: default-server
```

However am getting the error below.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=undertow/server=default/host=default/location=default' are not available:
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.handler.properties; Possible registration points for this capability: 
        /subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/file=*
        /subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/reverse-proxy=*
,121 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

Comment: The error message basically says that you're refering to `handler: properties`, but no `handler` named `properties` exists. It seems you define a `handler` named `default`. Can you try `handler: default`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the configuration that worked for me.

```
swarm:
  undertow:
    handler-configuration:
      files:
        properties:
          path: "${jboss.home.dir}/"
          directory-listing: true
        welcome-content:
          path: "${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"
          directory-listing: false
    servers:
      default-server:
        hosts:
          default-host:
            alias: localhost
            locations:
              /prop:
                handler: properties
              /:
                handler: welcome-content
            http-invoker-setting:
              security-realm: ApplicationRealm
        https-listeners:
          default-https:
            enable-http2: true
            security-realm: ApplicationRealm
            socket-binding: https
        http-listeners:
          default:
            enable-http2: true
            redirect-socket: https
            socket-binding: http
    servlet-containers:
      default:
        default-buffer-cache: default
    default-virtual-host: default-host
    default-servlet-container: default
    default-server: default-server
```